# How to break line after every record in 2D araylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello I have a input file like-

```
item1;item2;item3
element1;emement2;element3
field1;field2;field3
```

I want to add elements from this input file to a 2D araylist but I am not able to break record after every row.

I coded something like.

```
public class reader{
List<List<String>> file_column = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> file_row = new ArrayList<String>();
String cust_inputfile = "C:/inputfile.txt";
BufferedReader cust_br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cust_inputfile));
while ((cust_line = cust_br.readLine()) != null){
        file_row.addAll(cust_line);
        file_column.add(cust_row);
}
System.out.println(file_column);
}
```

it gives the following output-

```
[[item1;item2;item3, element1;emement2;element3,field1;field2;field3]]
```

and i want output like-

```
[[item1;item2;item3]
[element1;emement2;element3]
[field1;field2;field3]]
```

please suggest the necessary changes, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the declaration:

```
List<String> file_row = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Inside the while loop. What you do now is just add the elements to the existing file_row. You want a new list for each line.

Comment: I want that every item should come in new line in the cust_column list

Comment: thanks but it did not worked it now gives output like-                     [[ item1;item2;item3],[element1;emement2;element3] [field1;field2;field3]]

Comment: There is no way to do that out of the box with lists. As they implement a toString of their own, which prints it as they way you see. So either you have to make your own type of list with a proper toString() or you can just loop over them to pretty print them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the elements in the row and add them to the list:

```
while ((cust_line = cust_br.readLine()) != null){
        file_column.add(Arrays.asList(cust_line.split(";")));
}
```

Comment: Thanks i tried that, it only splitted the every item of every row by semicolan and while displaying printed coma instead of colan.

Comment: The colon is displayed, because you have a list of lists of strings. I assumed that is what you wanted, since you had this declaration: List<List<String>> file_column = new ArrayList<List<String>>();